# Android Application listens to TCP port

Tags: java, android, server, tcp-port

I have figured out how to check if the port is open or not in my server.

However, I am facing an issue that how to check the numbers of other devices listening to the specific port.

My flow of application is:

First, my application will check if my server's port is open or not.

Second, if the port is open, it will need to check the number of devices listening to the TCP port.

Third, if port reach specific number, lets say 20 devices listening to the TCP port, I will need the application to listen to following port for port availability.

Can someone enlighten me about this case?

Comment: Only the server listens in TCP. Do you mean 'connected'? and why the limit of 20? and the new port?

Comment: Hi EJP, I have around 3000 devices will be connecting to the port and limit of 20 is just an example of limit specific number of device in a port.

I try to avoid congestion or bad traffic by having multiple ports availability for devices.

Comment: Having a large number of connections to a single TCP port does not cause congestion or 'bad traffic', and using multiple server ports where you could have used one just wastes server resources. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Because every devices will be sending data to the port for interval time of every 5 seconds.

Comment: So? Using multiple ports doesn't help that in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

> I have figured out how to check if the Port is open or not in my server.

There was never any mystery about that. Just try to connect to it.

> However, I am facing an issue that how to check the numbers of other devices is listening to the specific port.

The *server* is listening to the port. The devices are *connected* to it.

> My flow of application is that,
>
> Firstly, my application will check if my server's port is open or not.

In other words your application connects to the port.

> Second, if the port is open, it will need to check the number of devices listening to the TCP port.

Why?

> Third, if port reach specific number, lets say 20 devices listening to the TCP port, I will need the application listen to following port for port availability.

Why?

> I have around 3000 devices will be connecting to the port and limit of 20 is just an example of limit specific number of device in a port.

There is no such thing as 'limit specific number of device in a port'. You can have many thousands of simultaneous connections to the same TCP port. Web servers do this 24 hours a day.

> I try to avoid congestion or bad traffic by having multiple ports availability for devices.

Using a single port does not cause congestion or 'bad traffic', and using multiple ports where you could have used one just wastes resources at the server.

There is no point in this. It is based on a serious misunderstanding of TCP.

Comment: I know your point it can listen even in thousands of devices in one port. But my program which is window service program that is listening to port and saving data to database in every 5 seconds. I'm afraid it will be congested if I just use one port.

Have you created a program that can handle thousand of devices and saving to database without a problem?

Comment: I can only repeat what I have already stated. You have a serious misunderstanding of TCP. Having lots of connections to a single port *does not cause congestion.* The amount of network traffic is exactly the same whether it is 1000 connections to one port or 1000 connections to 1000 ports. I also repeat that Web servers do exactly this 24 hours a day. Thousands of concurrent connections to stackoverflow.com port 443, for example. And please stop saying 'listening' when you mean 'connected' or 'receiving'. Don't misuse standard terminology.